# ActionScript 3.0 textInput and Display

Tags: flash, actionscript, textbox, adobe, textinput

I am new at flash, the below is my script, i have 3 textinput boxes, name1, name2, name3 and 3 dynamic texts, output1, output2, output3. Once the user, enters the text in the box, it should appear exactly the same in the dynamic output text. It works for the first one, but does not work for the second and third one. I renamed changehandlers differently to remove compile errors, but now only the first one works. Is there a better way of doing this, if i want to have multiple textbox entrees?

```
name1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    output1.text = name1.text

}
name2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler1(e:Event):void 
{
    output2.text = name2.text;
}

name3.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler2(e:Event):void 
{
    output3.text = name3.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change the name of the listener functions in the latter two `addEventListener()` calls. It currently calls `changeHandler()` on all three events.

You should have:

```
name2.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler1);
name3.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler2);
```

---

You can create a class that manages joining the input text field with the output text field:

```
package
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TextBinder extends Object
    {
        // vars
        private var _input:TextField;
        private var _output:TextField;

        /**
         * Joins input with output
         * @param inp The input text field
         * @param outp The output text field
         */
        public function join(inp:TextField, outp:TextField):void
        {
            _input = inp;
            _output = outp;

            _input.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, _change);
        }

        /**
         * Event.CHANGE
         */
        private function _change(e:Event):void
        {
            _output.text = _input.text;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can loop through your text fields and join them using this:

```
var tb:TextBinder = new TextBinder();
tb.join(name1, output1);
```

Comment: thank you good sir, this works perfectly, but i feel there must be a more efficient way to to do this, for each text field, i have to write one like this, can i do a loop or something similar to achieve better results.

Comment: See update. You could refine this to be even better using classes, which I can update and give an example of as well.

Comment: the loop has no errors, but does not seem to work, when i type something in the textbox, nothing changes in the dynamic text (output)

Comment: Odd, should probably test code before I post it. I'll take a look at it later on. I do recommend creating a class that contains a TextField property for both the input and output. This class then can handle the updating and everything for you rather than loops etc.

Comment: i have tried doing what you say, i am very clueless on how to approach this. Thanks for your help, if you could provide this class that would be most appreciated.

Comment: i removed the package, and the public / private because i am in Flash CS5, but i still get lots of errors. am i doing something wrong

Comment: Take a look at this for how to implement: http://junk.projectavian.com?f=textfield.zip

Comment: i tried implementing the file system to the way you did it, did not work, that dose not matter though, i used the files you gave me, added the boxes, and var tb:TextBinder = new TextBinder();

tb.join(name1, output1);
tb.join(name2, output2);
tb.join(name3, output3);

only the third one works

Comment: You need to make a new TextBinder for each join.

Comment: var tbA:TextBinder = new TextBinder();
tbA.join(name1, output1);

var tbB:TextBinder = new TextBinder();
tbB.join(name2, output2);

var tbC:TextBinder = new TextBinder();
tbC.join(name3, output3);